# SmartTarget not displaying promotion attached on global publication

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I have installed SmartTarget 2013 Sp1, Everything is working fine but when I create a promotion for Global publication (marking include child publication in SM UI) is not returning promotion for local publication.

Promotion are returning properly if I create same promotion directly for child publication.

Here is BP layout

- Level 30: Where we are creating Content.
- Level 50: Where we create page
- Level 70: promo where we are publishing content and page.

Here If I create promotion for Level 70 site, promos are returning properly but if I create promotion for level 50 site, promotion are not returning If I visit site 70.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself, but it was explained to me once that SmartTarget works with Blueprinted promotions as follows:

When running a query in a child publication, it actually runs the query in the parent publication, and then transposes the publication ID of the returned CPs to 'localize' the result.

Hence if your content is not published from the publication where you create the promotion, you will not see any results.

Its explained more fully in the [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-89150A23-9762-4A12-A9C7-437ED47C2166)

Answer (score 0):

Please attached your logs fr detail.

But you must check 
1. that components must be published from MasterSite also.
2. SmartTarget config in your master and local website must be correct.

Thanks
Harish Sharma